# Snap SVG animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael, snap.svg

Hi All I'm trying to figure out how to code an animation using [Snap SVG](http://snapsvg.io).

I know there are plenty of ways to achieve what I'm looking for which is really just a simple animation but am not sure what I am doing wrong.

So I have a couple of SVG files that I want to animate on a click event but I have tried several times to do this but nothing is animating.

Currently this is what I have:

```
<script>
  var paper= Snap(5000,5000);
  var c = paper.image("clock machine.svg", 100,100,500,480);
  var b = paper.image("new years ball.svg", 306,20,200,200);
  var l = paper.image("lights.svg",306,20,200,200);
  var p = paper.image("button.svg", 158,508,35,35);
  var s = paper.image("LCD screen mask.svg", 265,454,263,85);
  var g = s.group(b,l);
  var clickFunc = function ()  {
    g.transform ('');
    g.animate({transform : "t0,200" }, 2000, mina.backin );
  }
  g.click( clickFunc );
</script>
```

The images load and appear to work but I cannot get them to animate properly. Ultimately, I'm looking to animate the group of  var B and var L when a user clicks var p.

If anybody is familiar with snap svg or raphael js and knows how to animate using those perhaps you can help me out? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you want var g = paper.group(b,l); rather than s.group(b,l). Often 's' is used instead of 'paper' for Snap, but you need to match the initialisation. The rest looks ok I think.

Answer (score 1):

**In order to animate SVG in SNAP you should append it  using a code similar to**

```
Snap.load("image.svg", function (f) {
  g = f.select("g");
  s.append(g);
});
```

I found this code on http://www.developerdrive.com/2014/01/introducing-snap-svg/